# Voting on questions you've answered (or which have interesting answers)

Tags: discussion, voting

This is more an observation that surprises me than a meta question needing an answer.

When I answer a question it's only because I found it interesting enough to spend time on. That seems to me to call for upvoting the question, which I do. If I find someone else's answer to a question interesting I upvote both the answer and the question.

I'm surprised that this doesn't happen more regularly. I often see an interesting question with a thoughtful answer, with upvotes on the answer and none on the question, so clearly none from the answerer.

Comment: When I find a question interesting, I usually _forget_ to vote, I'm occupied with other things then. Not always do I remember later.

Comment: Related: [Should you upvote a question if it has enlightening answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20875/should-you-upvote-a-question-if-it-has-enlightening-answers) and [About not upvoted, answered questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/about-not-upvoted-answered-questions). (And also [Why don't people upvote questions they answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/509/why-dont-people-upvote-questions-they-answer) on meta.SO.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak That related question does nearly duplicate mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I always find it strange when there is a relatively simple question that quickly receives an answer, but no up vote. If a question is interesting enough to answer most of the time I think it would be worth an up vote.

I can think of cases where this might not be, but I would think it would be more rare. But it seems to be really common.

I often find that google brings me to other stack exchanges. Often to simple questions that I need help with. I always stop and up vote these since it was useful to me even if it was unlikely to be intriguing to the experts. I probably up vote 5-10 simple questions about LaTeX every week for this reason.

So, I think there is real value in having simple questions too, if they are clearly stated, not repeated a million times and clearly answered.

When I write an answer I hope to be what people will find when they search for that question. I want my answer to be the helpful one that makes someone's study session or project easier.

So, I nearly always up vote questions that I answer.

But I'm starting to think I may be doing something wrong since few people seem to do the same.

Comment: There are no rules about voting, so you're not doing anything wrong by upvoting a lot.